# What does version info in ldd -v mean?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ldd, readelf

```
Version information:
    /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.0.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgfortran.so.3 (GFORTRAN_1.0) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3
        libgfortran.so.3 (GFORTRAN_1.4) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
```

So there are 3 rows of `libc.so.6`, versioned at `GLIBC_2.xx`.

What does that mean? What version of libc.so.6 does this `liblapack.so` require?

How can I get `liblapack.so`'s version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does that mean?

It means that `liblapack.so` requires versioned symbols from `libc.so.6` with versions `GLIBC_2.2.5`, `GLIBC_2.4` and `GLIBC_2.14`. You can read about versioned symbols [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SymbolVersioning).

> What version of `libc.so.6` does this `liblapack.so` require?

It requires `2.14` or newer. In general, GLIBC never removes symbols, only adds new ones, and so will still provide symbols versioned at `GLIBC_2.2.5` even in the latest GLIBC-2.24.

If it did ever remove such "old" versioned symbol, that would break any old binaries that depended on that symbol (which is why it's not done).

> How can I get liblapack.so's version?

It doesn't look like `liblapack.so` itself is using any versioned symbols. You can look at your package manager to find out what version of `liblapack.so` you have. Something like:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so
liblapack-dev: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so

dpkg -l liblapack-dev
...
ii  liblapack-dev  3.5.0-2ubuntu1  amd64 Library of linear algebra routines 3 - static version
```