# understanding ldd verbose: what are the multiple versions?

Tags: dynamic-linking, ldd

When I run ldd in verbose mode, I get output like that below. What does it mean when multiple versions are listed? Does that mean that any of those versions workable, or that it needs all those versions?

```
    ldd -v lbrycrd-linux\ \(4\)/lbrycrdd 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd167cf000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007eff77399000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007eff77191000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007eff76df3000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007eff76bdb000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007eff767ea000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007eff79f90000)

        Version information:
        lbrycrd-linux (4)/lbrycrdd:
            ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
            librt.so.1 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
            libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.27) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
            libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
            libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
            libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean when multiple versions are listed?

It means that your binary references *symbols* with these versions. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558104/50617) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36387635/50617) answer.

> Does that mean that any of those versions workable, or that it needs all those versions?

The latter. Or rather, it needs a library that *provides* all of these symbols, which generally means `GLIBC_2.27` *or* later for GLIBC, and `GCC_4.2.0` *or* later for `libgcc`.